# ng-repeat on two arrays

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to do a ng-repeat on an array which is composed of two arrays, like this :

```
[titles: [], links: []]
```

My arrays (titles and links) have the same length
What i want to print in my ng-repeat, finally, is anything like that :

```
{{ array.title }}
{{ array.link }}
```

For example, in a C program i have to do that :

```
int i;

i = 0;
while (titles[i])
{
    printf("%s - %s", titles[i], links[i]);
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's not clear how you have your data — `[titles: [], links: []]` isn't meaningful.

Ideally you would arrange your data as an array of objects that looks like:

```
var array = [{title: "foo", link: "bar"}, {title…etc]
```

Then you could just use:

```
<div ng-repeat="obj in array">
   {{obj.title}},  {{obj.link}}
```

If you **know** that titles and links will always be the same size you can do this, but it's not very pretty and might be a little fragile:

```
<div ng-repeat="title in titles">
   {{title}}, {{links[$index]}}
</div>
```

Comment: I think he said, titles and links are arrays

Comment: Thank you, your post helped me, i don't know why i haven't store my datas in objects... that is so evident ! :)

Comment: One stupid thing that angular does is ordering the array objects in alphabetical order when doing an ng-repeat

Answer (score 7):

This is how it worked for me:

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="name in product.names">
    Buy {{name}} for {{product.prices[$index]}}
</ion-item>
```

I had both product.names and product.prices of same size

Answer (score 2):

If the length is the same, then make it an object rather than two arrays.

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/6iAf0tcPAVYk3K8IQWOb?p=preview)

```
<ui ng-repeat="movie in movies">
  <li>{{movie.t}} located in {{movie.l}}</li>
</ui>
```