# How to use AngularJS to make these two sections repeat?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, frameworks, frontend

I am trying to make two sections in my HTML repeat itself. The first section is supposed to repeat itself twice and the second section is supposed to repeat itself four times.

Here is what the second section in particular looks like(I want this to repeat four times) [image]

Here is my current progress - [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u1ux5gek/)( wo Angular JS applied to the second) and [Fiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/u1ux5gek/2/)(w AngularJS).
I got the first section to repeat twice but when I apply the repeat directive to the second section, the second section disappears....

To accomplish both tasks, I used the AngularJS [Ng-Repeat](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_repeat_array) directive. I made sure to only [bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12860595/how-to-define-two-angular-apps-modules-in-one-page) or initialize the Angular app once in a outer div that contains both sections. I followed syntax from [Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25109901/ng-repeat-on-two-arrays) to group data together in JavaScript. I haven't read anything that says you can't have more than one ng-init(I used two to initialize data for the two sections)

```
<div id="rest_contents" data-ng-app=""> .....
```

Does anyone see an issue with my syntax or what I did wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your console log, there is a syntax error with your sections list definition. You have `pictorial=` but it should be `pictorial:`

```
<div data-ng-init="sections=[{title: 'Campaign', pictorial:'campaign.png'},
         {title: 'TV Ads', pictorial:'tv_adds.png'} , {title:'Video Archive',pictorial: 'video_archive.png'},
    {title: 'House Showcases', pictorial: 'house_showcases.png'}]" >
```

Comment: Thanks!!! Can't believe I forgot to do that. Did I structure everything right - directives, etc?

Comment: happens to us all, sometimes you just need a fresh pair of eyes. Structure looks right. Just a note, if you plan to use `pictorial` as the img src in the future, remember to use the `data-ng-src` attribute.

Comment: Would I still need that attribute if I am getting the photos from within the working directory, not through the Internet? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc

Comment: Pretty much whenever the image `src` value is going to be an evaluated angular model variable then use `ngSrc` regardless of where the photo is located. Not a train smash if you don't, but say you use `<img src="{{srcVal}}"></img>` then the browser will make 2 web requests. First one to the url `{{srcVal}}` which will be invalid of course and the second one once angular evaluates `srcVal`. If you use `ng-src={{srcVal}}` then the browser will only make 1 request once angular evaluates `srcVal`