# AngularJS - mixed ng-repeat, one after another

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

How can I achieve the output of two `ng-repeat` so that they are mixed.

Current output:

```
john
maria
peter
red
blue
green
```

Desired output:

```
john
red
maria
blue
peter
green
```

of this:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat='item in names'>{{item.name}}</div>
    <div ng-repeat='item in colors'>{{item.color}}</div>
 </body>
```

However, I don't want to use `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end` as I'm using stagger animation.

[PLUNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/tIjF6ly82h6Lss9A2ztd)

Many thanks

**EDIT**: hypothetically, both data are coming dynamically from different sources, hence they're not in one/same object.

Answer (score 2):

You could use $index to show the number like so:

```
<div ng-repeat='item in names'>
      {{item.name}}
      <br>
      {{numbers[$index].number}}
</div>
```

However, I would recommend putting the names and numbers in one object as that would be better practice.

Comment: Changed my question, as I don't need numbers. Both data might be coming in dynamically, hence they're are not in one object.

Comment: The answer still applies. Just use colors[$index].color instead of numbers[$index].number

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably handle this by iterating over the underlying objects, if that's possible given your data. For example:

```
people = {[{"name":"name1", "age":"age1"}, {"name":"name2", "age":"age2"}]}

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl" ng-repeat='person in people'>
<div>{{person.name}}</div>
<div>{{person.age}}</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should combine the names and numbers into a single object.  Then you could simply do:

```
<div ng-repeat="combo in combinations">
    <div>{{combo.name}}</div>
    <div>{{combo.number}}</div>
</div>
```

I would look at the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25109901/ng-repeat-on-two-arrays).

Answer (score 0):

If we have 2 ng-repeats like-

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="comp-names" ng-repeat="compNames in $ctrl.data.compNames track by $index">{{compNames}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="comp-desc" ng-repeat="compDesc in $ctrl.data.compDesc track by $index">{{compDesc}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Map the 2 arrays in the controller first-

```
ctrl.combined = ctrl.data.compNames.map(function(value, index){
    return { name: value, desc: ctrl.data.compDesc[index] };
});
```

and then iterate over the resulting array-

```
<tr ng-repeat="comp in $ctrl.combined track by $index">
    <td class="comp-names">{{comp.name}}</td>
    <td class="comp-desc">{{comp.desc}}</td>
</tr>
```

For the detailed solution and discussion, please refer the link below-

[To display results of 2 ng-repeats alternately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48231638/to-display-results-of-2-ng-repeats-alternately/)